# Create Subclasses in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a subclass in my service class where I can declare functions with the same name but with different usages.

I want to be able to write:

```
httpWrapper.get //default is observables. returns observable
httpWrapper.promise.get //returns promise-variant
```

My current service:

```
export class HttpWrapperService {
    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

    public get<T>(endpoint: string, options?: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
        return this.http.get<T>(endpoint, options);
    }
    public post<T>(endpoint: string, data: any, options?: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
        return this.http.post<T>(endpoint, data, options);
    }
    public delete<T>(endpoint: string, options?: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
        return this.http.delete<T>(endpoint, options);
    }
}

export namespace HttpWrapperService {
    export class Promise {
        constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private readonly http: HttpClient) { }
        public get<T>(endpoint: string, options?: any) {
            return this.http.get<T>(endpoint, options).toPromise();
        }
        public post<T>(endpoint: string, data: any, options?: any) {
            return this.http.post<T>(endpoint, data, options).toPromise();
        }
        public delete<T>(endpoint: string, options?: any) {
            return this.http.delete<T>(endpoint, options).toPromise();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I write `httpWrapper.` I only get the observable variants. I can't choose the promise-variants.

How can I do this?

I basically want intellisense to show me when I type: `httpWrapper.`:

```
httpWrapper.post
httpWrapper.get
httpWrapper.delete
httpWrapper.promise
```

And when I've selected `httpWrapper.promise.`:

```
httpWrapper.promise.get
httpWrapper.promise.post
httpWrapper.promise.delete
```

Comment: why not simple `httpWrapper.getPromise` instead of `httpWrapper.promise.get`?

Comment: furthermore, how is `httpWrapper.promise.get` less repetitive than doing `httpWrapper.get.toPromise()`?

Comment: another tip: your wrapper service has wrong method signatures. As soons as you dont pass an `options` parameter or one that doesnt have the keys `observe: "events"` and `reportProgress: true`, the return type is simply `Observable<T>`

Comment: and if you pass one with the pair `observe: 'response'` then the return type will be `Observable<HttpResponse<T>>`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Okay. Hold on, i will try to answer all of your questions. `1`&`2`: readability and preferability (also, i think it is easier to refractor if functionality in the wrapper changes). `3`: Not sure what you mean by this. The options param is optional? `3`: what do you mean by signature parameters? `4`: You lost me :/. If you have ways to help me with any problems that might occur with my current solution, I will be happy to approve it as the answer.

Comment: At the end, both approaches `httpWrapper.get.toPromise()` and `httpWrapper.promise.get` break the law of demeter in different ways, and are equally repetitive. In terms of encapsulation/readability, `httpWrapper.getPromise` is the clear winner. But hey, I just wanted to challenge your way of thought.

Comment: The methods of the `HttpClient` have different return types depending on the overload that you use, which depends on specific values of the `options` parameter. See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Comment: @Jota.Toledo sure, however I want to expand on these namespaced-functions later on and this is just the start. This was just the simplest way I could imagine doing a structured function-list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpWrapperService {
    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

    public get<T>(endpoint: string, options?: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
        return this.http.get<T>(endpoint, options);
    }
    public post<T>(endpoint: string, data: any, options?: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
        return this.http.post<T>(endpoint, data, options);
    }
    public delete<T>(endpoint: string, options?: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
        return this.http.delete<T>(endpoint, options);
    }

    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-classes-per-file
    public promise = new class {
        constructor(private wrapper: HttpWrapperService) { }
        public get<T>(endpoint: string, options?: any) {
            return this.wrapper.get<T>(endpoint, options).toPromise();
        }
        public post<T>(endpoint: string, data: any, options?: any) {
            return this.wrapper.post<T>(endpoint, data, options).toPromise();
        }
        public delete<T>(endpoint: string, options?: any) {
            return this.wrapper.delete<T>(endpoint, options).toPromise();
        }
    }(this);

}
```

I can now call these functions with:

```
//different service
constructor(@Inject(HttpWrapperService) private readonly httpWrapper: HttpWrapperService) {}

public letsUseHttpRequests(machine: Machine){
    this.httpWrapper.post<Machine>(endpoint, machine); //observable
    this.httpWrapper.get<Machine>(endpoint); //observable
    this.httpWrapper.delete<Machine>(endpoint); //observable
    this.httpWrapper.promise //classContainer
    this.httpWrapper.promise.get<Machine>(endpoint); //promise
    this.httpWrapper.promise.post<Machine>(endpoint, machine); //promise
    this.httpWrapper.promise.delete<Machine>(endpoint); //promise
}
```

Comment: Was just about to propose something similar :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Even though I solved it myself - I would love to see what you had in mind, I've seen some of your other posts and I really enjoy your work. There might be other people who would like a somewhat different solution also. :)

Comment: It was literally the same, anonymous class instantiated to a field. Namespace-class merges the stuff in the namespace with the static part of the class was the extra info I would have added :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Sidenote: For some reason I'm required to use `HttpEvent` in my observable <T>. But my other calls do not like this. How can I do my observable functions without the use of `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`. Shouldn't Observable<T> work? strange...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toPromise` method on an `Observable<T>`.
That's it.

## Example

`httpWrapper.get //default is observables. returns observable`

`httpWrapper.get.toPromise() //returns promise-variant`